# Compute increases and decreases of items in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes (of identical cols) of products, numbers and values. They represent products in a shop during two different months.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['LAPTOP', 'CELL_PHONE', 'DRONE', 'WATCH'],
                   'Number': [10, 100, 50, 20],
                   'Value': [1000, 5000, 3000, 1000]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['LAPTOP', 'DRONE', 'WATCH', 'IPHONE'],
                    'Number': [30, 50, 15, 150],
                    'Value': [2700, 3000, 750, 6000]})
```

df1 is the previous month's data and df2 is the current-month's data. I want to find the differences in the inventory. Ideal output must be 3 dataframes like these:

diff_df:

```
Product Number  Value
LAPTOP  +20     +1700
WATCH   -5      -250
```

New_Products_df:

```
Product     Number  Value
IPHONE      150     6000
```

discontinued_products_df:

```
Product     Number  Value
CELL_PHONE  100     5000
```

This is what I have done so far (minimal):

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
print("\n")
print(merged_df)
```

and, it gives the below result. I have to somehow match the left_only and right_only rows and get differences. Perhaps, I am doing it in a round-about way. Is there a cleaner way to do what I need to do?

```
      Product  Number  Value      _merge
0      LAPTOP      10   1000   left_only
1  CELL_PHONE     100   5000   left_only
2       DRONE      50   3000        both
3       WATCH      20   1000   left_only
4      LAPTOP      30   2700  right_only
5       WATCH      15    750  right_only
6      IPHONE     150   6000  right_only
```

Answer (score 2):

From you result df after `merge` we need split the df by the unique count (`nunique`) and `indicator`

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
x=merged_df.groupby('Product')['_merge'].agg(['nunique','first'])
merged_df=merged_df.drop('_merge',1)
diff_df=merged_df[merged_df.Product.isin(x.index[x['nunique']!=1])].groupby('Product').agg(lambda x : x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[-1])
New_Products_df=merged_df[merged_df.Product.isin(x.index[(x['nunique']==1)&x['first'].eq('right_only')])]
discontinued_products_df=merged_df[merged_df.Product.isin(x.index[(x['nunique']==1)&x['first'].eq('left_only')])]
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a small change to diff: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0] to get do  df2 - df1 (where df2 is current month and df1 is previous month data).

Answer (score 2):

You can get a difference using [`df.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) after setting `Product` as the index in both the dataframes

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Product')
df2 = df2.set_index('Product')
df2.sub(df1).dropna()

         Number   Value
Product
DRONE       0.0     0.0
LAPTOP     20.0  1700.0
WATCH      -5.0  -250.0

# If you only want values with changes i.e. either +ve or -ve use `df.query`.
df2.sub(df1).dropna().query("(Number != 0 ) & (Value != 0)")

#          Number   Value
# Product
# LAPTOP     20.0  1700.0
# WATCH      -5.0  -250.0
```

To get newly added `Product` use [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)

```
idx = df2.index.difference(df1.index)
df2.loc[idx]
         Number  Value
Product
IPHONE      150   6000
```

To get discontinued use [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html)

```
idx = df1.index.difference(df2.index)
df1.loc[idx]
           Number  Value
Product
CELL_PHONE     100   5000
```